# Set dynamic variables in foreach loop

Tags: php, variables, foreach

I have a set of categories I want to loop through, and set a dynamic variable/array as the page loops.

The code I currently have is:

```
foreach($categories as $category)
{
    $category_ads[] = Advert::listforPageArea(2, 1, $category['id']);
}
```

The `Advert::listforPageArea` function returns an object of an advert based on what category is chosen.

I want to be able to calculate the expiry date of each advert to use elsewhere.

I'm struggling to explain exactly what I want, but I simply want to set custom content within a loop.

Comment: Hard to understand what you're asking for here. Can you use some psedocode to explain what you want?

Comment: I'll use invalid code but hopefully this will explain what I want:

    foreach($categories as $category)
    {    
        $ad_ . $category['shortname'] = Advert::listforPageArea(2, 1, $category['id']);   
    }

That would give me a set of objects like:

$ad_business, $ad_innovation and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're searching for is called 'variable variables'.

See http://foundationphp.com/blog/2010/12/18/understanding-php-variable-variables/

The linked blog entry also answers the question of variable scope (contrary to Geoffroy's answer, variable variables are valid outside of the loop they are created in) and states (correctly) that this method is highly insecure without validating the variable names.

Could you go with an array within an array instead? `$arr['cat1']['cat2']`

EDIT: how to do this with multidimensional arrays (see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

```
$ads = array(); // not explicitly needed, but clarifying
// ... some code
foreach($categories as $category)
{
    if(!array_key_exists($category, $ads)) { $ads[$category] = array(); } // not explicitly needed
    $ads[$category['name?']][] = Advert::listforPageArea(2, 1, $category['id']);
    // or (see comment below)
    $ads[$category][] = Advert::listforPageArea(2, 1, getCategoryField($category, 'id'));
}
```

!!! Important: You're using `$category` like a variable one time and like an associative array the other time. You can't simply evaluate an array to a string. I guess your array `$category` may contain some field `name?`, as it seems to contain a field named `id`. You'd have to use that field name in `$ads[$category['field???']][]` *or* your line `Advert::listforPageArea(2, 1, $category['id']);` is not correct.

Comment: Thanks for that. I found variable variables earlier, but couldnt figure out how to use them.

I'm trying this: $$ad_ . $category['shortname'] = Advert::listforPageArea(2, 1, $category['id']);

But its invalid. Any suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion would be to drop variable variables and go with two dimensional array as Martin mentions. This will prevent your scope getting cluttered and you'll know what variables are available as well.

Comment: Can you provide an example of this? I'm not sure what syntax I have to use .

Comment: Thanks Martin.

My code is as follows
$ads = array();
// ... some code
foreach($categories as $category)
{
    if(!array_key_exists($category['id'], $ads))
    {
        $ads[$category] = array();
    }
    $ads[$category['shortname']][] = Advert::listforPageArea(2, 1, $category['id']);
}

Which gives me this error: Warning: Illegal offset type
Also what code would you expect to be executed where you have commented //some code here

Comment: [Arrays and objects can not be used as keys. Doing so will result in a warning: Illegal offset type.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) Probably your `$category['shortname']` is an object, which you must first cast to a string: `$ads[(string)$category['shortname']][]=...`. Hope this helps.

Comment: `//... some code` means that your array `$ads` may have been declared further above, depending on what you want to do with it. If you use the array in that `for loop` for the first time, there'll be no `some code`...

Answer (score 0):

The content you set in your loop will be restricted to that loop. So it won't be usable elsewhere (as far as I remember).

If you want you can create a variable like :

```
//In the foreach loop
$cat_name = "whatever";
$var_name = $cat_name . "_expiryDate";

$$var_name = 5 /* Calulcate the expiry date here */;
```

To be able to access your variables elsewhere, you will need to store the value outside of the loop, such as in an associative array.

One other solution would be to include the expiry date in the Advert object, or expose a method to get it in the class.

Comment: The scope of these created variables is the surrounding function, not the loop.

Comment: Okay thank you :) I wasn't sure, problem when switching to C/C++ all the time :)